# Sides of triangle based on coordinates in C

Tags: c

So this code should calculate the size of **a** and **b** side and Height of triangle and I am too dumb to realize what is wrong, can someone help me locate misstake? Thanks for help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

float distance(float, float, float, float);

int main()
{
float a, b, c, d;
float aX, aY, alfa;
float bX, bY, beta;
scanf("%f %f %f" , &aX, &aY, &alfa);
scanf("%f %f %f", &bX, &bY, &beta);
distance(aX, aY, bX, bY);
float gamma = 180 - alfa - beta;
c = distance(aX, aY, bX, bY);
b = ((c/sin(gamma)) * sin(beta));
a = ((c/sin(gamma)) * sin(alfa));
d = (sin(alfa))*c;
printf("Side a:%.2f\n Side b:%.2f\n Side c:%.2f Height:%.2f\n", a, b, c, d);
return 0;
}

float distance(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2)
{
float dx = x2 - x1;
float dy = y2 - y1;
return sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you use degrees instead of radians. Trigonometric functions have to be applied to values measured in radians.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. I am just a student so I do not know how these functions work at all. But I could read it on the website where I find it ... I am soo dumb ...